# Incorrect if statement in django template

Tags: python, django, templates, if-statement, django-templates

I want to make a list of works which are still in progress and which are completed.
When all the work has been completed - a list of work "in progress" will be empty.
At the present moment I have this code, but it is bad. Because when I have all the work done, there is a heading "In progress". And just when all the work is in progress.

```
<h3>{% trans 'In progress' %}</h3>                        
{% for worked_on in worker.worked_on.all %}
    {% if worked_on.is_project_in_progress %}
       //Text here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My model:

```
class WorkerWorkedOnProduct(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, verbose_name=_('Worker'), related_name='worked_on')
    description = models.TextField()
    is_project_in_progress = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_the_project_is_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
models.BooleanField(initial=True)
```

instead of 'default', because if you set the default=True, it will always return as True.

Comment: for model fields, default=True actually does what you want. Initial=True is for form fields

Answer (score 0):

The default=True is fine, if that's what you want. You'd probably want to fix this in the view, actually. One thing you could do, is get a queryset of 'in progress' works and put that in the template context from the view. If you do it that way, you can simply test if it contains *any* objects at all with something like {% if in_progress_stuff %}your_header{% endif %}

Comment: I have this, but problem still exists: 
`                        {% if is_project_in_progress %}
                        <h3>{% trans 'In progress' %}</h3>
                        {% endif %}`

Comment: You're looping through a queryset of WorkerWorkedOnProduct objects, all of which may or may not have the boolean value turned on. If you want the h3 to only appear when *all* the objects are in the same state (be it True or False, whichever you want), you should just check for this condition in the view, and add a new boolean value to your context